# In Qt how to add a file with a QFileDialog in a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, c, qt, qlineedit, qfiledialog

I have one window which has a button named "..." which open an other window which has also a button named "..." which open a QFileDialog. Next to the button of the second window, there are 10 QLineEdit to get 10 files. With the QFileDialog, I can't take a mp3 file and put his name in the first QLineEdit. How can I do ? And if the first QLineEdit is already took, how can I put the name of a mp3 file in the second QLineEdit ?

The file "main.h" has just the include of Qt. Here is my code and I tried many solutions without success :

```
#include "main.h"

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
QApplication    program(argc, argv);
/* ******************** First Window ******************** */
QWidget         window;
QVBoxLayout     layout;

window.setWindowTitle("Programme");
window.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Bouclier.png"));
window.setFixedSize(450, 400);

    QHBoxLayout     layouttop;
            QLabel          labeltop("Nom du programme :");
            QLineEdit       lineedittop;

                layouttop.addWidget(&labeltop);
                layouttop.addWidget(&lineedittop);

    QHBoxLayout     layoutmiddle;
            QPushButton     buttonnext;
            QPushButton     buttonprevious;
            QPushButton     buttonetc("...");
            QLineEdit       line0;
            QLineEdit       line1;
            QLineEdit       line2;
            QLineEdit       line3;
            QLineEdit       line4;
            QLineEdit       line5;
            QLineEdit       line6;
            QLineEdit       line7;
            QLineEdit       line8;
            QLineEdit       line9;

        QVBoxLayout     layoutleft;

                layoutleft.addWidget(&buttonnext);
                buttonnext.setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Haut.png"));
                layoutleft.addWidget(&buttonprevious);
                buttonprevious.setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Bas.png"));

        QVBoxLayout     layoutcenter;

                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line0);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line1);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line2);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line3);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line4);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line5);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line6);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line7);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line8);
                layoutcenter.addWidget(&line9);

                line0.setReadOnly(true);
                line1.setReadOnly(true);
                line2.setReadOnly(true);
                line3.setReadOnly(true);
                line4.setReadOnly(true);
                line5.setReadOnly(true);
                line6.setReadOnly(true);
                line7.setReadOnly(true);
                line8.setReadOnly(true);
                line9.setReadOnly(true);

        QVBoxLayout     layoutright;

                layoutright.addWidget(&buttonetc);

                layoutmiddle.addLayout(&layoutleft);
                layoutmiddle.addLayout(&layoutcenter);
                layoutmiddle.addLayout(&layoutright);

    QHBoxLayout     layoutbottom;
            QPushButton     buttonapply("Apply");
            QPushButton     buttoncancel("Cancel");

                layoutbottom.addWidget(&buttonapply);
                layoutbottom.addWidget(&buttoncancel);

layout.addLayout(&layouttop);
layout.addLayout(&layoutmiddle);
layout.addLayout(&layoutbottom);
window.setLayout(&layout);
window.show();
/* ******************** First Window ******************** */
/* ******************** Second Window ******************** */
QWidget         windowed;
QVBoxLayout     layouted;

windowed.setWindowTitle("Session");
windowed.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Bouclier.png"));
windowed.setFixedSize(450, 400);

    QHBoxLayout     layouttoped;
            QLabel          labeltoped("Nom de la session :");
            QLineEdit       lineedittoped;

                layouttoped.addWidget(&labeltoped);
                layouttoped.addWidget(&lineedittoped);

    QHBoxLayout     layoutmiddled;
            QPushButton     buttonnexted;
            QPushButton     buttonprevioused;
            QPushButton     buttonetced("...");
            QString         file;
            QLineEdit       lined0;
            QLineEdit       lined1;
            QLineEdit       lined2;
            QLineEdit       lined3;
            QLineEdit       lined4;
            QLineEdit       lined5;
            QLineEdit       lined6;
            QLineEdit       lined7;
            QLineEdit       lined8;
            QLineEdit       lined9;
            QComboBox       box;
            QLabel          label("Durée :");

        QVBoxLayout     layoutlefted;

                layoutlefted.addWidget(&buttonnexted);
                buttonnexted.setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Haut.png"));
                layoutlefted.addWidget(&buttonprevioused);
                buttonprevioused.setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Bas.png"));

        QVBoxLayout     layoutcentered;

                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined0);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined1);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined2);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined3);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined4);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined5);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined6);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined7);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined8);
                layoutcentered.addWidget(&lined9);

                lined0.setReadOnly(true);
                lined1.setReadOnly(true);
                lined2.setReadOnly(true);
                lined3.setReadOnly(true);
                lined4.setReadOnly(true);
                lined5.setReadOnly(true);
                lined6.setReadOnly(true);
                lined7.setReadOnly(true);
                lined8.setReadOnly(true);
                lined9.setReadOnly(true);

        QVBoxLayout     layoutrighted;

                layoutrighted.addWidget(&buttonetced);

        QVBoxLayout     layoutmore;

            QHBoxLayout     layoutmored;

                layoutmored.addWidget(&label);
                layoutmored.addWidget(&box);

                box.addItem("30");
                box.addItem("60");

                layoutmore.addLayout(&layoutmored);

                layoutmiddled.addLayout(&layoutlefted);
                layoutmiddled.addLayout(&layoutcentered);
                layoutmiddled.addLayout(&layoutrighted);
                layoutmiddled.addLayout(&layoutmore);

    QHBoxLayout     layoutbottomed;
        QPushButton     buttonapplyed("Apply");
        QPushButton     buttoncanceled("Cancel");

                layoutbottomed.addWidget(&buttonapplyed);
                layoutbottomed.addWidget(&buttoncanceled);

layouted.addLayout(&layouttoped);
layouted.addLayout(&layoutmiddled);
layouted.addLayout(&layoutbottomed);
windowed.setLayout(&layouted);
/* ******************** Second Window ******************** */
/* ******************** Actions First Window ******************** */
QObject::connect(&buttonetc, &QPushButton::clicked, &windowed, &QWidget::show);
/* ******************** Actions First Window ******************** */
/* ******************** Actions Second Window ******************** */
QObject::connect(&buttonetced, &QPushButton::clicked, [&windowed, &file] {file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(&windowed, QObject::tr("Sélectionner un fichier son ..."), "C:/", QObject::tr("Audio (*.mp3)"));});
lined0.setText(Qstring(file));
/* ******************** Actions Second Window ******************** */

return program.exec();
}
```

Comment: you already get the filename returned. just set it as the text of a line edit. and you can check before if this text is empty or not.

Comment: @Hayt, I added just under the QFileDialog ```lined0.setText(QString(file));``` and lined0 is the first QLineEdit but nothing append.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to emit the address of filename in one window and then receive this address in the second window by slot function

Comment: Or you can name the filename as a global variable,QFileDialog can open a path,and then assign this path to the filename,QLineEdit also use this global variable